# Error: Element or attribute type specified more than once in XML SCHEMA Collection

Tags: xml, schema, xml-schema-collection

What's wrong with my XML SCHEMA Collection  :x, it is throwing error.

Here is an example of XML for which I wrote an XML SCHEMA COLLECTION:

```
<ReviewRules xmlns="urn:goldleaf-schema:ReviewRules" version="1.0">
    <Name>Never Apply Review Rule</Name>
    <ReviewBasis>Never</ReviewBasis>
    <DefaultReviewerComment>Review not required as per rule.</DefaultReviewerComment>
    <PayLimit AutoReject="True">20000</PayLimit>
    <UserLimit AutoReject="True">25000</UserLimit>
    <DailyTotalLimit AutoReject="True">50000</DailyTotalLimit>
    <TotalLimit AutoReject="True">75000</TotalLimit>
</ReviewRules>
```

XML SCHEMA COLLECTION:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns ="urn:GAPS-schema:ReviewRules" 
            xmlns:mstns ="urn:GAPS-schema:ReviewRules" 
            targetNamespace="urn:GAPS-schema:ReviewRules" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="ReviewRules" type="mstns:ReviewRulesType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="ReviewRulesType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="ReviewBasis" type="mstns:ReviewBasisType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="DefaultReviewerComment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="PayLimit" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
        <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:attribute name="AutoReject" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="UserLimit" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
        <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:attribute name="AutoReject" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="DailyTotalLimit" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
        <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:attribute name="AutoReject" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>          
      <xsd:element name="TotalLimit" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
        <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:attribute name="AutoReject" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" fixed="1.0" use="required">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Version attribute should be fixed and increase if there is any schema change for review rules.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="ReviewBasisType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
      <xsd:enumeration value="Never" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="Always" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="Limits" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

This XSD not able to validate the XML and giving error:

**Element or attribute type specified more than once. Location: '/*:schema[1]/*:complexType[1]/*:sequence[1]/*:element[4]/*:complexType[1]'.
Msg 6314, Level 16, State 1, Line 3**

Answer (score 0):

You might find Saxon's error messages more helpful:

```
Error at xsd:element on line 11 column 84 of test.xsd:
  A <complexType> element must not appear as a child of an <xsd:element> with a @type attribute
Error at xsd:element on line 16 column 85 of test.xsd:
  A <complexType> element must not appear as a child of an <xsd:element> with a @type attribute
Error at xsd:element on line 21 column 91 of test.xsd:
  A <complexType> element must not appear as a child of an <xsd:element> with a @type attribute
Error at xsd:element on line 26 column 86 of test.xsd:
  A <complexType> element must not appear as a child of an <xsd:element> with a @type attribute
Schema processing failed: 4 errors were found while processing the schema
```

Basically, you can specify the type of an element either with a type attribute, or with a complexType child element, but you can't have both - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok I agree, but type of an element as attribute gives the same error. Tried this also

`<xsd:element name="DailyTotalLimit" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
         <xsd:attribute name="AutoReject" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
    </xsd:element>`

Comment: Well that's a different error. You can't have xs:attribute as a child of xs:element. Don't try guessing XSD syntax - you will never get it right by guessing.